# SPOJ problem - The last digit of a number to a power

Tags: c, programming-challenge, mathematics, time-limit-exceeded, integer

[Here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASTDIG/) is the problem statement:

> Given integers \$a\$ (\$0 \le a \le 20\$) and \$b\$ (\$0 \le b \le 2,147,483,000\$), where \$a\$ and
>   \$b\$ are not both 0, find the last digit of \$a^b\$.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of input contains an integer \$t\$, the number of test
>   cases (\$t \le 30\$). \$t\$ test cases follow. For each test case will appear \$a\$
>   and \$b\$ separated by a space.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case output an integer per line representing the result.
>
> **Example Input:**
>
> ```
> 2
> 3 10
> 6 2
> ```
>
> **Example Output:**
>
> ```
> 9
> 6
> ```

Here is the code which is exceeding the time limit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        long long int base,exponent;
        scanf("%lld%lld",&base,&exponent);
        if(base==0&&exponent==0)
        {
            printf("1\n");
        }
        else
        {
            long long int digit=1;
            long long int i;
            for(i=1;i<=exponent;i++)
            {
                digit=(base*digit)%10;
            }
            printf("%lld\n",digit);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I make this more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have probably noticed, this is not efficient because you have a loop running `exponent` times (which could be over 2 billion). The way to make this more efficient is not to make your code faster, but to choose a better algorithm.

I'm not going to tell you outright what the answer is, but do the following. Add some output to your loop:

```
        for(i=1;i<=exponent;i++)
        {
            digit=(base*digit)%10;
            printf("digit = %d\n", digit);
        }
```

and then run your program for some (small) sample inputs. You should notice a pattern. The key is to identify the pattern and use it to avoid running the loop a billion times.